# Is there any way to see data coming from bluetooth?

Tags: command-line, bluetooth

Is there any way I can see the data being transfered to my PC Bluetooth from my Android device ? Something like a [Bluetooth Terminal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sena.bterm&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5zZW5hLmJ0ZXJtIl0.) in Android but in Ubuntu. I am sending Strings and some simple data from my Android Device and I would like to see them in Ubuntu Terminal.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [hcidump](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/bluez-hcidump) [image: Install bluez-hcidump]

We can monitor raw HCI data transmitted from or to a Bluetooth device with **hcidump** from the package **bluez-hcidump**:

```
hcidump [-i hciX] [--save-dump=<file>]
```

If no option is given hcidump will assume the first device available. Otherwise we need to specify the device we want to monitor (e.g. `hci1`). If needed we can optionally dump the traffic to a file specified with option `--save-dump=`.