# How to dump data from bluetooth device (heart rate monitor)?

Tags: bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth heartrate monitor (chest strap) and I would like to find out how I can dump the data from the connection.

I have tried the steps outlined in: 
[Is there any way to see data coming from bluetooth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190779/is-there-any-way-to-see-data-coming-from-bluetooth)
But I could not see any relevant data  with `hcitool -x` although connected.

What do I have to do to read the raw bytes/data sent from the monitor ?

The heart rate monitor is confirmed to be working over bluetooth.

Comment: Use wire shark software.  [install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/700712/how-to-install-wireshark) and fix somethings to work on super user mode.  Then open it goto bluetooth monitoring section and so on